# Search to be tolerant to unicode vs ascii punctuation

Tags: feature-request, search

The search ["this pull request couldn't be reverted automatically"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=this+pull+request+couldn%27t+be+reverted+automatically) was not finding [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221775/git-revert-a-revert-for-a-merge). The reason was that a single quote symbol in the message was replaced with apostrophe ("couldn’t"). Now I edited the question, so that is worked around (to be honest I don't know what's really in the message if one copies it from the github's UI(*)). It is however not a first time unicode punctuations sneak info messages or even code snippets in internet pages - long dash vs minus, quotation marks vs double quotes, and now this.

It would be nice if a text which contains such unicode punctuations could be found as one with their ASCII conterparts. And maybe the other way around as well.

(*) it was found that the message is copied with apostrophe. This makes "the other way around" feature important. However, subjectively I still feel like ASCII version is still the common way to write texts and should be able to be searched.

Comment: That's why you should use a real search engine instead of SO search...

Comment: (note that if the copied-pasted text from GitHub has that smart quote, somebody may copy and paste the error message and could not find the post as well...)

Comment: I think it’s because it’s formatted as code. It shouldn’t be.

Comment: @Laurel was it? I think this way to format called "quote" and sort of proper way to quote messages.

Comment: Usually I use code blocks to quote things that looks good in monospace font (compiler error message for example), but the feature called blockquote is "> content"